# Why is there no lookup method for Python sets?

Tags: python, set

In Python, objects can be equal despite not being the same object (`==` vs. `is`). Consider the following sequence for arbitrary objects `obj1` and `obj2`.

```
assert obj1 == obj2
assert obj1 is not obj2
s = set((obj1,))
del obj1
```

Is there a general and efficient method to obtain `obj1` from `s` and `obj2` (for arbitrarily large sets `s` happening to contain an object that is equal to the one being looked up)? (It seems that constructs relying on `set.intersect`ing singleton `set`s are not reliable.)

If not, why?

The obvious alternative is to use a `dict` where each key is stored as its own value. It's not clear how much memory that approach wastes compared to the prospective `set`-based approach.

Comment: So what use-case did you envision that requires that behaviour, and which dictionaries can't solve?

Comment: The only use case I could come up thus far is a temporary `intern`ing mechanism. But the question still seemed interesting from an academic pov.

Comment: Python is a practical language; little is done purely because it might be interesting academically. Interning is done with a mapping, not a set.

Comment: See [Python's string interning code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.1/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l165) for example: *This **dictionary** holds all interned unicode strings*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, sets are not mappings, If `obj1 == obj2`, it *should not matter*. Sets are there to test membership and to hold unique *values* (as defined by equality), not to map back to specific objects. Use a dictionary for that instead.

Otherwise, you'd have to iterate and pick the one object that is equal:

```
obj1 = next(ob for ob in s if ob == obj2)
```

Sets in Python were borne out of the `dict` type, in that before sets were added (in 2.3 in the form of the [`sets` module](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#pep-218-a-standard-set-datatype), then as a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-218-built-in-set-objects)), you used dictionaries that mapped all keys to `None` to track unique values. Adding 'lookup' functionality would undo this specialisation; there is no need to add functionality to sets that dictionaries already offer, especially since dictionaries have since grown many other set features such as set algebra operations.

Comment: Might be better to set a default on `next`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: depends; is it an error for the object not to be in the set?

Comment: Ah yes. That makes sense

Comment: While the answer says "no", it lacks the interesting part: The rationale. It would be a relatively simple matter to expose the requested functionality, but it apparently is not done for a good reason.

Comment: @HelmutGrohne: again, there is no use case for that. All functionality in software has a cost, and that cost is to be justified. Sets are not used to map equality to a unique object, not when you have dictionaries already. Dictionaries do lookups just fine. Sets were added to the Python language because dictionaries were used to find unique values (mapping everything to `None`). Why then have sets go the other way again?